# Fastest route to 99 lives in Super Mario World

Tags: super-mario-world, speedrun

Starting from a fresh game of Super Mario World (SNES), what sequence of levels should be played in order to reach a lives total of 99 as quick as possible?

From my experience with the game, I know that there are a few levels that are very effective for 1-up farming, but many of them are a little far into the game, and so might not be optimal from a speed-running perspective.

There could be multiple ways to answer this question, (like in a one or two player scenario, for example), so I should clarify that what I'm looking for is for one player to have a life total of 99.

Comment: @Nelson I suppose that this scenario might not fall under the classical definition of speed-running. My understanding of a "speed-run" is to play a game attempting to reach a specific objective as fast as possible, sometimes with conditions applied. While this objective is normally beating the game, wouldn't it be just as valid to pursue an arbitrary objective like reaching a certain life count?

Comment: I think competing for 99 lives is a plausible challenge - if somewhat boring, because the optimal route to maximum lives is likely to involve lots of repetitive farming in most games with Mario-like life systems. Super Mario World is no exception.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you want to get 99 lives as fast as possible from a fresh start, I believe the optimal solution is not to race to later levels but to spam Yoshi's Island 2, where you can quickly get several extra lives by using the Koopa shell near the start. Just throw it at the line of Koopa Troopas and run after it to keep it on screen. If done correctly, you should be able to get five extra lives within 15 seconds of starting the level (probably even slightly less, but I can't test it right now). Since you start with 4 lives, repeating this process 19 times should suffice.

You have to complete the level once, after which you can exit the level midway after gaining the lives. Assuming each attempt takes about 15 seconds, plus maybe additional 30 seconds for finishing the level for the first time, you'll be packing 99 lives in about five minutes fifteen seconds from a fresh start.

(it is also possible to use a glitch in Yoshi's Island 2 to inject arbitrary code in the game ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OPcV9uIY5i4)), including the possibility to add any amount of lives but since it's both insanely difficult and likely to be considered bad sport I'll leave it as a footnote)

Answer (score 2):

I think the fastest way is grey coins in Vanilla Secret 2. Get the gray P button near the Spinys, hit the button at the beginning of the level, collect the grey coins, gain a lot of lives. This isn't too far into the game. I would argue that if you take the lake path instead of the cave path in Donut Plains, you could finish it in well under 15 minutes, possibly even under 10.

Answer (score 2):

Vanilla Secret 2, but just jump on the koopa paratroopas back and forth with the cape equipped. Don't use Yoshi because he'll destroy them.
Jump on the paratroopas and regular koopas, but do not land on the shells or shellless koopas and the regular koopas should respawn as you go back and forth.
It's 1up per jump but its more involved, requires less travelling and restarting, and you can finish off by grabbing the silver coin trick near the end of the level with the pswitch and spinies to get an extra 6 lives.